# Query Custom Setting from any Salesforce Org using UserName and Password

Tags: authentication

The question can also be viewed as: how to obtain sessionID without oAuth?

Since, here we would need to query from any Salesforce org using Username and password, we can not use oAuth(which would need to be set in each org we would like to query)

and, since we are querying from Salesforce, we do not have a Apex Login method to get the SessionID

How to query Custom Setting from one Salesforce Org, by using just UserName and Password?

Comment: I too had the same problem when I had to query few data from API user through back-end. The answer below helped me and I am using the below piece of code in all the places where I require SessionId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use **SOAP** login API to obtain Salesforce SessionId as below

  ```
   curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/36.0 
   -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" 
   -H "SOAPAction: login" 
   -d @login.txt
  ```
- **@login.txt** should contain content as below:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
      <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <n1:username>your_username</n1:username>
        <n1:password>your_password</n1:password>
      </n1:login>
    </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>`

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm

Comment: could you please share the equivalent in Apex or JavaScript?